# Parent to child connection not wiring up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, relational-database

I've got an EntityFramework based database here created by code first approach. The database contains two tables with a parent-child-relationship between them:

1. `Orderlists` (based on model *"Orderlist"*)
2. `Orders` (based on model *"Order"*)

where Orderlists contains an *`ICollection<Order> Orders`* which should (!) list all related orders. For some reason it doesn't.

The DbContext of the controller contains two DbSets:

1. `DbSet<Orderlist>`
2. `DbSet<Order>`

The model *Order* on the other hand has got two properties (with its type in brackets):

1. `int OrderlistId`
2. `Orderlist OrderList`

In the controller in a [HttpPost] *Create* method for a new *Order* object I'm wiring up this relation by picking the appropriate *Orderlist* object (with the correctly provided/selected ID) from the DbContext, setting *OrderlistId* and *Orderlist* of the newly created *Order* object appropriately and adding the *Order* to the *Orders* collection of the picked *Orderlist* (creating the collection if it is null).

Then I do a `db.SaveChages();` which does what it's supposed to do.

When the database is generated at first from the code of the models, regarding the relationship only the *OrderlistId* property generates a field in the datatables. Neither the *Orders* collection of the *Orderlist* nor the *Orderlist* property of the *Order* generate fields in the tables. That's okay since it is still a valid relation: the ID of the *Orderlist* is a PK and the *OrderlistId* value is set correctly. The schemes of the datatables also reflect the relation by foreign keys.

Now, the problem is that the relation isn't restored when processing the data at a different point in my application. The *Orders* ICollection is **always** *null* when I pick it from the DbContext.

My question is: should the **Orders** `ICollection` be filled automatically when creating the `DbContext` object? Or do I have to fill it manually by iterating through the Orders `DbSet` of the `DbContext` and add every appropriate Order manually to its related Orderlist? And, if I have to, where and how do I have to do that?

Comment: not directly related, but I would use a camelCasing, or all-lower casing naming convention if you were to put up code examples...

Comment: Since the question has already been answered I'll consider this advice for future posts and leave this question as is. I fear, I'd build in mistakes and confusions if I edited it now after it has been answered. Is that alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All association properties in Entity Framework Code First models must be marked with the *virtual* keyword, if you want Entity Framework to automatically load the associated entities on-demand (lazy-loading).

The following (basic) model definitions should work.

```
public class OrderList
{
    public int OrderListId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } // note the use of virtual
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int OrderListId { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderList OrderList { get; set; } // note the use of virtual
}
```

Also, note that when adding an Order to an OrderList, you don't have to set the association properties on the Order entity.  You can simply add the the new Order to the Orders collection on the OrderList entity, like this:

```
int orderListId = 1;
OrderList orderList = context.OrderLists.Find(orderListId);

Order newOrder = new Order();
orderList.Orders.Add(newOrder);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively, you could just set the OrderListId property on the new Order, and add it to the DbContext Orders collection.

```
Order order = new Order();
order.OrderListId = 1;
context.Orders.Add(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yeah, that did the job! Thanks a lot!